# Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, "Profile" unit test causes error: file contains no data buffers

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, profiling

After right-clicking a unit test in Test Explorer in Visual studio 2019, and selecting "Profile", the following happens:

- All associated projects all built and instrumented, as evidenced by output by Test logging to the Output window, like `** Instrumented C:\Users\Me\Source\Repos\MyRepo\<ProjectPath>\Project.UnitTests\bin\x64\Debug\net472\MyProject.dll **`
- The unit test runs and passes
- A new tab with a name of "[UnitTestName][Date][Time].VSP" appears with "Preparing to open report..." in the middle
- An error occurs, "File contains no data buffers"

I've made sure all the projects have this in their csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Also made sure symbol servers are set up.  Any ideas what else to try to get profiling of unit tests working in VS2019?

Comment: What version of VS 2019 are you on? Are you all up to datE?

Answer (score 1):

Through trial and error, discovered there are two things that need to be set to get the Profile option to work (using Visual Studio 2019 and NUnit 3 adapter):

1. You need the project under test and any of its dependencies switched
   to target "Any CPU", under Project > Properties > Build tab >
   General section > Platform Target dropdown.
2. From the Visual Studio bar, Test > Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects - change it to x64.

Profiling should then work.  If you don't do the second step, you'll get Test output errors like:
`Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.`
and/or
`No test matches the given testcase filter 'MyTestName'`

Comment: Those steps didn't help me. I still see "File contains no data buffers". Any other suggestions?

Comment: I got it work by setting some things in my .csproj files as explained in: https://www.benday.com/2021/07/23/profile-a-unit-test-in-visual-studio-fails-with-file-contains-no-data-buffers/ : `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>`